# integration of functions using greatest integer function

Tags: integration

Integrate the function $[sin(x)]$ where $[x]$ represent integral part of  $x$ from lower limit $0$ to upper limit  $(2n-1)\pi$......  now my problem I have seen that it is  symmetric about  odd $\pi/2$  but I am not able to form a definite pattern by drawing the graphs also please can anyone explain that how to deal with this

Comment: Is $[-0.5] = 0$ or $[-0.5] = -1$? The latter is standard (it behaves nicer since it doesn't make $0$ or negative numbers special in any way but treats all numbers equally), but it's good to be clear.

Comment: @Arthur: the "truncate towards zero" definition would make the question fairly easy :)

Comment: Please learn how to typeset the formulas with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

The sine is positive for arguments in the even half-periods ($[2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$) and negative otherwise, so that the integer part is $0$ and $-1$ respectively. (The points where the sine is $1$ have zero measure and can be ignored.)

So your integral is $-\pi(n-1)$.